# Setting a pointer which other objects point to, to null

Tags: c

I have a function which takes in a struct (pointer). Within this function, I iterate through to the end of a queue of structs which is global and add the new struct to the end of the queue. After I complete this operation, for the purposes of error checking, I need to set the struct (pointer) that was passed in to be equal to null without affecting the global queue. However, when I set the struct passed in to be equal to NULL this causes a segfault for the queue.

Edit: I can't post the full code as it is sensitive to a class however I can post an example.

Example:

```
//There is code above this parsing the passedInJob in various ways, adding it to the queue if the final step
//This block of code just adds to queue, after this all references to the newly added job cause a segfault
//get the current head of the queue and put it in currJob
struct job * currJob = queue->head;

//Move to the end of the queue
while(currJob->nextJob != NULL)
   //move to the next job, when we hit NULL we're at the end
   currJob = currJob->nextJob

//Set the end of the queue to be the passed in job
currJob->next_job = passedInJob;

//We set passedInJob = NULL because at the end we check if the job still exists to signify there was an error adding the job
//This is causing the error, I believe setting this to NULL is setting the struct in the queue to NULL
passedInJob = NULL;

//Since there is code parsing above, we use this to ensure the job was added
if(passedInJob)
  //handle error
```

Comment: post the code for better understanding of your question

Comment: See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sounds like the newly created struct has been GC'd when it goes out of local scope.

Comment: Eyeballing segfault is not easy with incomplete code snippets.   If you cannot post your complete code, you might want to diagnose it yourself with valgrind or  using https://segfault.stensal.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].